# I want to send only 1 item in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, edit

I have a bit of trouble here, when I do onClick, I hope I can take 1 item, and the handleUpdate() work great

```
const [langs,setLangs] = useState([]); 

function handleUpdate(item){
    console.log(item);
}
{langs.map((item, index) => {
<tr key={index}>
    //Some code here
    <td className='text-primary' 
        style={{maxHeight: '21px',width: '8%',maxWidth: '300px'}} 
        onClick={()=>handleUpdate(item)}>
              <ModalEditNgonNgu item={item}/>
    </td> 
</tr>
}
```

but I don't know why in 'ModalEditNgonNgu' I rendered all items like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZnJ3.png)

And When I tried to Edit, it can show only the first item, whatever I click.
This is ModalEditNgonNgu:

```
import '../../css/style.css';
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState, useSelector } from "react";
import { ajaxCallGetUrlDemo, ajaxCallPost } from "../libs/base";
import Select from 'react-select'
import { Const_Libs } from "../libs/Const_Libs";
import languagesList from "./languageList/country";
import { get } from 'jquery';


const ModalEditNgonNgu = (props) => {
const { handleGetLanguage } = props;
const [langName, setLangName] = useState("");
const [mainLangs, setMainLangs] = useState([]);
const [mainLang, setMainLang] = useState("");
const [titleLang, setTitleLang] = useState("");
const [describeLang, setDescribeLang] = useState("");
const [authorLang, setAuthorLang] = useState("");
const [rateLang, setRateLang] = useState("");
const [reviewsLang, setReviewsLang] = useState("");
const [translateList, setTranslateList] = useState([]);


const mainLangOptions = [
    { value: 'vi', label: 'Vietnamese' },
    { value: 'en', label: 'English' },
    { value: 'zh', label: 'Chinese' },
    { value: 'ja', label: 'Japanese' },
    { value: 'de', label: 'German' },
];
console.log(props.item);

const handleMainLang=(e)=>{
    const getMainLang = e.target.value;
    setMainLang(getMainLang);
}

const handleTransList=(e)=>{
    const getTransList = e.target.value;
    setTranslateList(getTransList);
}


const handleSubmit = () => {
    let arr = [{
        nameLanguage: langName,
        mainLanguage: mainLang,
        titleLanguage: titleLang,
        descriptionLanguage: describeLang,
        authorLanguage: authorLang,
        rateLanguage: rateLang,
        reviewsLanguage: reviewsLang,
        transLanguage: translateList
    }]
    console.log(arr);
    resetData();
    props.editLang(arr,props.item.id);
}

const resetData = () => {
    setLangName("");
    setMainLang("");
    setTitleLang("");
    setDescribeLang("");
    setAuthorLang("");
    setRateLang("");
    setReviewsLang("");
    setTranslateList([]);
}


return (
    <>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModalEditNgonNgu" style={{ fontSize: '14px' }}>
        {props.item.language_name}
        </button>
        <div>
            <div className="modal fade" id="myModalEditNgonNgu">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style={{ minWidth: '700px' }}>
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h4 className="modal-title">Sửa ngôn ngữ</h4>
                            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <form>
                                <div className="col">
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tên ngôn ngữ</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập tên ngôn ngữ...."
                                            defaultValue={props.item.language_name}
                                            onChange={(e) => setLangName(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tiêu đề</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập tiêu đề...."
                                            defaultValue={props.item.title_lang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setTitleLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Mô tả</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập mô tả...."
                                            defaultValue={props.item.describe_lang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setDescribeLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tác giả</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập tác giả (VD: Author)"
                                            defaultValue={props.item.author_lang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setAuthorLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Đánh giá</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập đánh giá (VD: Rate)"
                                            defaultValue={props.item.rate_lang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setRateLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Lượt đánh giá</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập lượt đánh giá (VD: reviews)"
                                            defaultValue={props.item.reviews_lang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setReviewsLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col">
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Ngôn ngữ chính</label>
                                        <Select 
                                            onChange={(e) =>setMainLang(e)}
                                            options={mainLangOptions}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Những ngôn ngữ dịch</label> 
                                        <Select 
                                            onChange={(e) =>setTranslateList(e)}
                                            isMulti
                                            isSearchable={true}
                                            options={languagesList}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleSubmit}>Update</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);
}

export default ModalEditNgonNgu;
```

Sorry if I wrote ambiguous, but I want to take correct 'item' whenever I click on the button that have language_name. What should I do?

Comment: It is hard to see what the issue is in the code you wrote. Please provide the full component code.

Comment: There are a couple of points of improvement here: 1. When you render new components inside `map` you should add `key` property to the component that let React know which component is the same component after rendering, like `<td key={item.id}...>`. 2. Using an arrow function in a property is not recommended since the component always gets a **new** function instance. So when you render the list all your items will be re-render.

Comment: Well, I added the ModalEditNgonNgu, so could you show me the error? Thanks

Comment: You render `<td ...><ModalEditNgonNgu item={item}/></td>` for all items, so the model will show up in every item, how do you control the modal visibility?

Comment: Actually, I started learning reactjs, so I watched some tutorial videos. I edited the first code like you say but it's still not work. And I think I shoud change the onClick to another new funtion, like this, what do you think?
```
function handleUpdate(item){
    console.log(item);
return(
    <ModalEditNgonNgu editLang={editLang}  item={item}/>
)
}
{langs.map((item, index) => {
<tr key={index}>
    //Some code here
    <td className='text-primary' 
        onClick={()=>handleUpdate(item)}>
              {item.language_name}
    </td> 
</tr>
}
```

Comment: You can't. I will post an answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information in your question. I will do my best to help you with your issue in the current context.

There are several issues in your code:

#### Modal Visibility

When you render the list of item, you constantly render the `ModalEditNgonNgu` for **every item**. I believe that it is not the desired behavior you want to get. Assuming you want to show the item you **clicked** on, you can do something like:

```
function App() {
    const [langs,setLangs] = useState([]);
    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(undefined);
    
    function handleUpdate(item){
        console.log(item);
        setSelectedItem(item);
    }

    return (<>
        <table>
            {langs.map((item, index) => {
                <tr key={index}>
                //Some code here
                    <td className='text-primary' style={{maxHeight: '21px',width: '8%',maxWidth: '300px'}} onClick={()=>handleUpdate(item)}>
                        This is item {item.id}
                    </td> 
                </tr>
             }
        </table>
       {selected Item && <ModalEditNgonNgu item={selectedItem}/>}
    </>);
}
```

In this code, we save the selected item in a state and create a **single** model based on the selected item.

Please note that this solution is not optimal. Most Modal implementation has some animations when they show up and disappear and should be shown by a property and not by the DOM. I guess you are using Bootstarp, so consider using some React wrapper like [React-Boostrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) and others.

#### Key property

When you render bunch of component in a loop, like `map`, you have to define a unique `key` prop to the child element, to let React follow and match different renders.

You added `<tr key={index}>` this is ok, but bad-practice. Key should be unique, index is **NOT** a good `key` value. The main goal of the `key` is let react track your componens. If you remove/insert items in the middle of the list, **different items** will have **same key** in **different renders**.

Since your item has an id property, you better do `<tr key={item.id}>`.

#### Arrow functions as props

Doing `<td ... onClick={()=>handleUpdate(item)}>` will work, but it creates a **new function instance** on every render, which will re-render every item in the list, every time that the list will be re-render.

It may be OK in your lightweight example, but it may cause performance issues in complex list, so you should avoid that.